# Segmentation Fault (core dumped) error pops up when I try and run my code

Tags: c, linux, terminal, segmentation-fault, project

```
`#ifndef MY_GAME_H
#define MY_GAME_H
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <curses.h>

#define EMPTY ' '
#define BORDER '*'
#define PLAYER 'P'
#define GOAL 'G'
#define COLLAPSED 'X'

typedef struct position {
    int row;
    int col;
} Position;

typedef struct node {
    Position pos;
    char collapsed_color;
    struct node* next;
} Node;

typedef struct list {
    Node* head;
    int size;
} List;

int ROW, COL;
char** map;
Position player, goal;
List history;

void initialize() {
    int i, j;

    map = (char**)malloc(ROW * sizeof(char*));
    for (i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
        map[i] = (char*)malloc(COL * sizeof(char));
        for (j = 0; j < COL; j++) {
            if (i == 0 || i == ROW - 1 || j == 0 || j == COL - 1) {
                map[i][j] = BORDER;
            }
            else {
                map[i][j] = EMPTY;
            }
        }
    }

    if (history.size > 0) {
        player = history.head->pos;
        goal = history.head->next->pos;
    } else {
        // initialize player and goal to default values
        player.row = 1;
        player.col = 1;
        goal.row = ROW - 2;
        goal.col = COL - 2;
    }

    map[player.row][player.col] = PLAYER;
    map[goal.row][goal.col] = GOAL;
}


void print_map() {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < COL; j++) {
            if (i == player.row && j == player.col) {
                attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));
                printw("%c ", map[i][j]);
                attroff(COLOR_PAIR(1));
            }
            else if (i == goal.row && j == goal.col) {
                attron(COLOR_PAIR(2));
                printw("%c ", map[i][j]);
                attroff(COLOR_PAIR(2));
            }
            else if (map[i][j] == COLLAPSED) {
                if (i == history.head->pos.row && j == history.head->pos.col) {
                    attron(COLOR_PAIR(3));
                    printw("%c ", map[i][j]);
                    attroff(COLOR_PAIR(3));
                }
                else {
                    printw("%c ", map[i][j]);
                }
            }
            else {
                printw("%c ", map[i][j]);
            }
        }
        printw("\n");
    }
}


void collapse_floor() {
    int i, j;
    Node* new_node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    new_node->collapsed_color = 'r';
    do {
        new_node->pos.row = rand() % (ROW - 2) + 1;
        new_node->pos.col = rand() % (COL - 2) + 1;
    } while (map[new_node->pos.row][new_node->pos.col] != EMPTY);
    new_node->next = history.head;
    history.head = new_node;
    history.size++;

    map[new_node->pos.row][new_node->pos.col] = COLLAPSED;
}    

void move_player(int row_offset, int col_offset) {
    if (map[player.row + row_offset][player.col + col_offset] == EMPTY) {
        map[player.row][player.col] = EMPTY;
        player.row += row_offset;
        player.col += col_offset;
        map[player.row][player.col] = PLAYER;

        collapse_floor();
    }
    else if (map[player.row + row_offset][player.col + col_offset] == GOAL){
        map[player.row][player.col] = EMPTY;
        player.row += row_offset;
        player.col += col_offset;
        map[player.row][player.col] = PLAYER;
        print_map();
        printf("\nYou Win!\n");
        exit(0);
    }
}

void undo_move() {
    if (history.size > 1) {
        Node* old_node = history.head;
        history.head = history.head->next;
        history.size--;

        if (map[player.row][player.col] == COLLAPSED) {
            map[player.row][player.col] = EMPTY;
        }

        player = history.head->pos;

        if (map[player.row][player.col] == COLLAPSED) {
            map[player.row][player.col] = PLAYER;
            map[old_node->pos.row][old_node->pos.col] = COLLAPSED;
        } else {
            map[player.row][player.col] = PLAYER;
            if (map[old_node->pos.row][old_node->pos.col] == COLLAPSED) {
                map[old_node->pos.row][old_node->pos.col] = EMPTY;
            }  
             map[old_node->pos.row][old_node->pos.col] = COLLAPSED;
        }

        free(old_node);
    }    
}

void end_game() {
    printf("Game over!\n");
    exit(0);  // Terminate the program with exit status 0 (success)
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int i;
    srand(time(NULL));

    if (argc != 7) {
        printf("Usage: ./game ROW COL player_row player_col goal_row goal_col\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    ROW = atoi(argv[1]);
    COL = atoi(argv[2]);
    player.row = atoi(argv[3]);
    player.col = atoi(argv[4]);
    goal.row = atoi(argv[5]);
    goal.col = atoi(argv[6]);

    if (player.row < 0 || player.row >= ROW || player.col < 0 || player.col >= COL ||
        goal.row < 0 || goal.row >= ROW || goal.col < 0 || goal.col >= COL) {
        printf("Invalid player or goal position.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    history.head = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    history.head->pos = player;
    history.head->collapsed_color = 'r';
    history.head->next = NULL;
    history.size = 1;

    initscr();
    start_color();
    init_pair(1, COLOR_BLUE, COLOR_BLACK);
    init_pair(2, COLOR_YELLOW, COLOR_BLACK);
    init_pair(3, COLOR_RED, COLOR_BLACK);

    initialize();

    print_map();

    while (1) {
        int ch = getch();
        switch (ch) {
            case 'w':
                move_player(-1, 0);
                break;
            case 'a':
                move_player(0, -1);
                break;
            case 's':
                move_player(1, 0);
                break;
            case 'd':
                move_player(0, 1);
                break;
            case 'u':
                undo_move();
                break;
            case 'q':
                end_game();
                break;
        }

        if (player.row == goal.row && player.col == goal.col) {
        end_game();
        }

        print_map();
    }

    endwin();

    for (i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
        free(map[i]);
    }

    free(map);

    while (history.size > 0) {
        undo_move();
    }

    return 0;
}



#endif /* MY_GAME_H */`
```

I'm currently working on a project and I'm having some trouble with a segmentation fault message that keeps popping up on my Linux terminal when I try to run my code with command line arguments. Specifically, when I try running the command: "./escape 7 8 1 1 5 3".

I've already tried debugging the code but unfortunately, I haven't been able to figure out what's causing the error. I initially thought that I may have been passing the wrong number of command line arguments, but after double-checking my code, I confirmed that I was passing in the correct 6 arguments.

Compiling my code hasn't been an issue, but I'm stuck on this segmentation fault message. I'm hoping that someone with more experience can help me pinpoint the root of the problem.

Comment: If you used a debugger, then at least add a comment in the code where the crash happens, and tell us the values of all involved variables.

Comment: As for making it simpler to debug and find the problem, try to scale back the code. Or better yet, don't write large parts of code without testing. Start with a small and little program, preferably an empty `main` function. The add a *small* and simple piece of code. Build (with extra warnings) and test. Do not continue until it builds cleanly and passes all tests. This way it will be very easy to isolate and figure out problems when they occur.

Answer (score 0):

Upon entry to the `initialize` function, the value of `history.size` is 1. So we take this branch of the if statement:

```
    if (history.size > 0) {
        player = history.head->pos;
        goal = history.head->next->pos; // Problem.
```

The problem is that `history.head->next` is `NULL`, so the code is referencing through a null pointer.

`player` and `goal` are already being set in `main`, maybe this was a refactor and `initialize` wasn't updated?

Comment: Would an update like this to the initialize function work:
  if (history.size > 0 && history.head != NULL && history.head->next != NULL) {
        player = history.head->pos;
        goal = history.head->next->pos;

Comment: That would stop the crash, but then the player and goal will _always_ be set to the default positions? Why can't you delete that whole if-else block, because you have already set player and goal in the main function?